# How do I use ALTER TABLE to ADD CONSTRAINT as an INDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, alter-table

I would like to use the `ALTER TABLE` command to `ADD CONSTRAINT`.  I do this often with no issues but in this case I need to add it as an `INDEX` as well.

From the Microsoft [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) it shows the following...

```
-- ALTER TABLE options

< table_constraint > ::=
 [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]
{
   {PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE }
     {
       NONCLUSTERED (column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,... n ])
       | NONCLUSTERED HASH (column [ ,... n ] ) WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = bucket_count )
     }
    | FOREIGN KEY
        ( column [ ,...n ] )
        REFERENCES referenced_table_name [ ( ref_column [ ,...n ] ) ]
    | CHECK ( logical_expression )
}

<column_index> ::=
  INDEX index_name
{ [ NONCLUSTERED ] | [ NONCLUSTERED ] HASH WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = bucket_count)}

<table_index> ::=
  INDEX index_name
{[ NONCLUSTERED ] HASH (column [ ,... n ] ) WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = bucket_count)
  | [ NONCLUSTERED ] (column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,... n ] )
      [ ON filegroup_name | default ]
  | CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE [WITH ( COMPRESSION_DELAY = {0 | delay [Minutes]})]
      [ ON filegroup_name | default ]
}
```

I usually do something like the following for adding a primary key and it works great (EX#1):

```
ALTER TABLE [table_one]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_7_table_one] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC) 
WITH(
    PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) 
ON[PRIMARY];
```

The SQL Server Management Studio scripts the table using the following (EX#2):

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_table_one]
ON [dbo].[table_one] ( [guid] ASC )
WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF
    ONLINE = OFF
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

So at the moment I'm doing the following (EX#3):

```
ALTER TABLE [table_one]
ADD CONSTRAINT [IX_7_table_one_guid] 
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([id] ASC) 
WITH(
    PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) 
ON[PRIMARY];
```

However, I feel like I'm missing something.  Like I need to have `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ([id] ASC)` (which I know will not work).  How do I make it show "Index" like this?

[image]

The issue being, when I create my new constraint using the above method (EX#3) the results of the `Type` on the constraint is a `Unique Key` rather than an `Index` like the previous image.

[image]

In the end, my goal is to use something like EX#3 to create the constraint using `ALTER TABLE` while ending up with a `Type` of `Index` instead of `Unique Key`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the problem is. Are you getting an error? What is the error? Why isn't what you have working or doing what you want?

Comment: Every unique constraint is implicitly backed by an index, there's no need to create that separately (in fact it would be nothing but wasteful to do so). You can, of course, also create a unique index on its own, but then it's not a constraint.

Comment: @ThomA sorry for the lack of directness on my question.  I've added more to the end to specifically describe the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, so does that mean there is ZERO difference between the two images at the end of my question?

Comment: The syntax you have included in your question is from the "Syntax for memory-optimized tables" section. Are you using those? (Doesn't look like it) The "Syntax for disk-based tables" section doesn't mention index in the `ALTER TABLE` grammar

Comment: I don't really know, I tend to ignore what the graphic designers of SSMS present. In scripts I trust. :P

Comment: @MartinSmith didn't even notice that, but TBH I'm not sure it matters in my case.  I just wanted to use `ALTER TABLE` to add constraints like I'm already doing in my example.  My code goes though each table and column to make sure they contain the correct signatures.  So if in ver1 of my app I require a table and column with no indexes, then later require that table and column to have a `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX` I want to alter the existing table to reflect the new signature.  I'm not trying to worry about memory optimization in any way, it just happens to be the example on the page.

Comment: The point is that for disc based tables you can use `ALTER TABLE` to add a constraint (implicitly backed by an index that can be defined as nonclustered) or `CREATE INDEX` to create a `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX` but you can't use `ALTER TABLE` to create a contraint-less index.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm not sure I really care about it TBH, I can go with never creating an `Index` type and always create a `Unique Key` instead.  It was just my OCD seeking completeness and accounting for every type of scenario I "might" come across.  I can just roll with what I currently have.  It was just bugging the hell out of me.  <insert Sheldon spasm meme>

Comment: Ahh that tracks with what I was looking into @MartinSmith and would make a great answer.  Basically it's not possible to use ALTER TABLE to create a UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX.  You have to use CREATE INDEX to achieve this instead.  Thanks!

Comment: yes. Or just to confuse the issue further you can create these "constraintless" indexes also as part of the `CREATE TABLE` syntax (since SQL Server 2014) but no analogue was ever added to the `ALTER TABLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the end, my goal is to use something like EX#3 to create the
> constraint using ALTER TABLE while ending up with a Type of Index
> instead of Unique Key.

This is not possible in the [Syntax for disk-based tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax-for-disk-based-tables).

You can use `ALTER TABLE  ADD <table_constraint>` to add a `unique` or `primary key` constraint.

Both of these are backed by indexes and you can define a lot of the possible index options but not all (no included columns or filter predicates for example).

In order to get something that shows up as type "index" it either needs to have been created at the same time as the table (as [`CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#full-syntax) does support defining inline indexes) or added subsequently with `CREATE INDEX`.